# Why is aluminium powder sticky?

Tags: material-science, physical-chemistry

Aluminium powder is used in applications like the “etch-a-sketch” toy because it tends to stick to surfaces. Also it tends to clog abrasive tools like files and grinding wheels or stones, and the chips are quite annoying to clean after machining, because they tend to stick everywhere.

What are the specific reasons related to its atomic structure for this phenomenon?

Comment: I find all fine metallic dusts to be sticky to be honest, not just aluminum. Also, there are files, stones, and wheels for aluminum. If you use one designed for something else, yeah it's not going to work out well. Kind of like if I used them on steel and asked why is steel so hard?

Comment: Well, those files, stones, and wheels for aluminum are designed to avoid this problem because it's real... And it would **absolutely not** be a stupid question to ask oneself what makes iron base alliages so hard because it's truly a property of iron and steel which made them have their own age after copper and bronze in antiquity.

Comment: Fine dusts side, I think the clogging is just due to the ductility of the aluminum (and copper). Jon Dossett, Practical Heat Treating (search around for it, you will find more than you want to know) goes into it with pages and pages of crystal structure. But in a word: crystal slip planes among other confounding factors (small grain apparently can increase ductility but we also know small grain size increases stiffness).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For *powders* where the mass of an individual particle is small relative to the size of the electrostatic effects due to slight charge differences on surfaces, "sticking" to those surfaces is common.

The reason why aluminum "loads" grinding wheels and files is 1) its ductility and 2) the fact that it exhibits *galling*- in which pieces of aluminum, when rubbed together under pressure, tend to friction-weld themselves together at asperities on their facing surfaces and then roll up into globs of aluminum that get sheared between the surfaces, glue themselves onto them, and then get sheared loose while tearing loose fresh aluminum from the now-roughened surfaces. So when a bit of loose aluminum gets jammed inbetween the teeth of a file, that aluminum rubs against the workpiece, galls itself into the interface, and then gets caught between more teeth on the file, etc., etc.

One reason this happens with aluminum is that when fresh aluminum surfaces are exposed to air, a very thin oxide film quickly forms on them- which can be rubbed away with sliding action to bring fresh, unoxidized aluminum on those surfaces into direct contact where "pressure welding" can occur, and the galling process initiated.

Comment: How comes that electrostatic effect could lead to attraction on conductive materials ? I would expect the charges to average over the whole lot (powder and machine, in the case of the chips due to machining) and if for some reason, the total would not be neutral, there should be repulsion instead of attraction, shouldn't it ?

Comment: @Camion Aluminium oxide is a good electrical insulator. As Niels said, freshly exposed aluminium oxidizes rapidly. And of course the surface area to volume ratio of the particles rises as the particles get smaller, and when they get flattened.